# cleaning data fails when using SIT

Tags: r

I am trying to format the data using the `bt.prep()` function. Can someone explain why this fails, and hopefully how to fix it? [Link to github repo](https://github.com/systematicinvestor/SIT/blob/master/R/bt.r)

```
library(quantmod)
#Systematic Investor Toolbox
sit = getURLContent('https://github.com/systematicinvestor/SIT/raw/master/sit.gz', binary=TRUE, followlocation = TRUE, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
con = gzcon(rawConnection(sit, 'rb'))
source(con)
close(con)

data <- getSymbols("USD/EUR",src="oanda",env=NULL)
bt.prep(data, align='remove.na')
```

Error is:

```
Error in b[[i]] : attempt to select more than one element In addition: Warning message:
In merge.xts(..., all = all, fill = fill, suffixes = suffixes) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rilcon42,

I think you need to create a `new.env()` before calling getSymbols...

```
library(quantmod)
library(RCurl)

#Systematic Investor Toolbox
sit = getURLContent('https://github.com/systematicinvestor/SIT/raw/master/sit.gz', binary=TRUE, followlocation = TRUE, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
con = gzcon(rawConnection(sit, 'rb'))
source(con)
close(con)

tickers = spl('USD/EUR')
dataRepo <- new.env()
getSymbols(tickers, src = "oanda", env = dataRepo, auto.assign = T)
bt.prep(dataRepo, align='remove.na')

head(dataRepo$USDEUR,6)
```

results:

```
> library(quantmod)
> library(RCurl)
> 
> #Systematic Investor Toolbox
> sit = getURLContent('https://github.com/systematicinvestor/SIT/raw/master/sit.gz', binary=TRUE, followlocation = TRUE, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
> con = gzcon(rawConnection(sit, 'rb'))
> source(con)
> close(con)
> 
> tickers = spl('USD/EUR')
> dataRepo <- new.env()
> getSymbols(tickers, src = "oanda", env = dataRepo, auto.assign = T)
[1] "USDEUR"
> bt.prep(dataRepo, align='remove.na')
> 
> head(dataRepo$USDEUR,6)
           USD.EUR
2015-01-11  0.8445
2015-01-12  0.8448
2015-01-13  0.8467
2015-01-14  0.8489
2015-01-15  0.8535
2015-01-16  0.8621
```